# Части речи УЖЕ и КАК и их значение в данной речевой конструкции

Tags: значение-слов

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли по данному сообщению судить о том, что девушка просто сравнивает себя с невестой посредством замены фаты тюлью, или сообщает о реальном выходе замуж?

Вот оригинал данного сообщения со страницы девушки в социальной сети:

> Пока меняют окна, тюль стал мне фатой и уже как новоиспечённая невеста-обязательное селфи с кошкой, чему она как всегда была очень рада))

Прилагается фото с тюлью, как с фатой. Само сообщение шутливое. В данном случае идёт сравнение себя с невестой, или сообщение о серъёзности намерений? Я не могу разобраться.

Comment: Мысль абсолютно неясна, она или как-то зашифрована, или просто небрежно или неграмотно записана.

Comment: Действительно, ничего не ясно.

Answer (score 1):

Меняют окна, тюлевые занавески временно сняли. Девушка просто фантазирует на тему "я невеста", представив себе, что занавески из тюля - это свадебная фата.
Пока меняют окна, тюлевые занавески стали её фатой, она вообразила себя "новоиспечённой невестой" и сделала селфи в этом воображаемом образе. Ни о какой "серьёзности намерений" речи здесь нет. Но и сказать, что это просто оторванная от реальности шутка тоже с уверенностью нельзя. Короче говоря, сообщение девушки не поддаётся однозначному толкованию.

Comment: Матвей, однозначный дать трудно. Девушке может предстоять свадьба вскоре, и она готовиться, репетирует перед свадьбой, представляет себя в роли невесты. А возможно, просто фантазирует.

Comment: Но "сообщения о серьёзности намерений" здесь вед нет, Серж. Здесь может иметь место намёк на предстоящую свадьбу, но это не факт.

Comment: В том-то и дело - намек. И это не факт. Поэтому я говорю, что нельзя однозначно говорить.